# Writing a jQuery function as a AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, jqlite

I need to write a **jQuery** **function** as a **AngularJS directive** but I don't know how to use specific jqLite functions *(closest, find..)* and *$(this)* inside my directive.

I've tried it like this:

jQuery Version:

```
$('.collapse-link').click(function () {
    var ibox = $(this).closest('div.ibox');
    var button = $(this).find('i');
    var content = ibox.find('div.ibox-content');

    content.slideToggle(200);
    button.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
    ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');

    setTimeout(function () {
        ibox.resize();
        ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
    }, 50);
});
```

My AngularJS directive:

```
.directive('iboxDirective', function($timeout){
      return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem){
          elem.on('click', function(){
            var ibox = angular.element('div.ibox');
            var button = angular.element('i');
            var content = angular.element('div.ibox-content');

            content.slideToggle(200);
            button.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
            ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');

            // This $timeout trick is necessary to run the Angular digest cycle
            $timeout(function(){
              ibox.resize();
              ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

The HTML file using the directive above:

```
<div class="ibox float-e-margins">
   <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Aktivitäten</h5>
      <div class="ibox-tools">
        <a class="collapse-link" ibox-directive>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
       Content...
    </div>
</div>
```

This way the directive triggers all ibox div's, but I want to trigger each one individually.

What am I doing wrong? Hope you can help me..

Comment: Why wouldn't you use existing Angular directives, for instance, ng-class?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @jbrown. If what you are trying to do is change classes on a trigger than [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) is what you want. Don't try to port jquery, just rewrite in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt use angular that way.

It may work but your comment in your code already tells you the reason

`// This $timeout trick is necessary to run the Angular digest cycle`

if you manipulate the DOM with no angular observed function you can get unexpected results and loose "connection" between DOM elements and your $scope.

Im not sure if I'm analysed correctly what your function does but here is an example plunker how you can do it: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aq6Zr6bYfdvhI01Ced83?p=preview)

Comment: This is a nice solution, but this way I have the same problem as described above. If I trigger the toggleCollapse function by clicking on the arrow icon, every ibox collapses. But I want to collapse only the ibox that I'm clicking on. Here is the modified plunker with the described behavoir: [ibox Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hHqsLmf4ykBfpAOdsgqN?p=preview)

Comment: this behaviour is normal, because you dont use the isolated scope of the directive. Thats the reason because it works in my plunker from above, because im rendering the html within the directive and have only access to the isolated scope.

Comment: to create an isolated scope add `scope: true,` to you directive object [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aFJh0jYNC3zxbsPTMLrB?p=preview)

Comment: Glad to help :)